# Change image through a dictionary on a django view

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-views

I am developing an application in django with support in several countries. On the site should appear the country flag according to the subdomain in which it is, but I can not find a way to send the necessary flag image through a django view.

This is a example of my views.py

```
def index(request):
   subdomain = request.META['HTTP_HOST'].split('.')[0]
    if subdomain == 'www':
        dic.update({"countryflag": ''})
    elif subdomain == 'mx':
        dic.update({"countryflag": '<img src="{% static "images/mxflag.png" %}" alt="img">'})
    elif subdomain == 'nz':
        dic.update({"countryflag": '<img src="{% static "images/nzflag.png" %}" alt="img">'})
    return render(request, 'mysite/index.html', dic)
```

I want to recive the variable "countryflag" in my basetemplate.html

```
<div id="cp_side-menu-btn" class="cp_side-menu">
    {{ countryflag }}
</div>
```

This doesn't works. I want to pass the entire image to the countryflag key. Is there a way to do this or I have to make an 'if' in the basetemplate.html?

Comment: What is the output of this code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please first create a dic and then for the template, I suppose this should work

```
{{ countryflag|safe }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update "dic" without initializing it in index().
Also add an else statement in case none of the three situations you declared are true.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes a few things.

1. You have your STATIC_URL = '/static/' configured in settings.py
2. You directory structure for the django project is 'ideal'

Directory Setup:

```
djangoproject
--djangoproject
----__init__.py
----settings.py
----urls.py
----wsgi.py
--myapp
----migrations
------__init__.py
----admin.py
----apps.py
----models.py
----tests.py
----views.py
--static
----css
------main.cs
----js
------main.js
--manage.py
```

djangoproject/djangoproejct/urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include # Add include to the imports here
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')) 
]
```

djangoproject/myapp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

You should then setup your myapp structure as such:

```
--myapp
----migrations
------__init__.py
----templates
------index.html
----admin.py
----apps.py
----models.py
----tests.py
----urls.py
----views.py
```

Your views.py

```
 def index(self, request, **kwargs):
       subdomain = request.META['HTTP_HOST'].split('.')[0]  
        if subdomain == 'www':
            context = {'data' : [ {'countryflag': ''}]}
        elif subdomain == 'mx':
            context = { 'data' : [ { 'countryflag' : '<img src="{% static "images/mxflag.png" %}" alt="img">'}] }
        elif subdomain == 'nz':
            context = { 'data' : [ { 'countryflag' : '<img src="{% static "images/nzflag.png" %}" alt="img">'}] }
        else:
            context = {'data' : [ {'countryflag': ''}]}
        return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
<div id="cp_side-menu-btn" class="cp_side-menu">
    {% for i in data %}
    {{i.countryflag}}
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

Comment: This approach was modified for your use case from [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-django-templates-static-files) by Amos Omondi from 2016.